# Have a "sticky" button right underneath another "sticky" navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an app file which contains my own custom appbar and different page components:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  appBar: {
          width:'100%',
  },
});

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="sticky" className={classes.appBar} />
      <Page1 show={someCondition} />
      <Page2 show={someCondition} />
      .
      .
      <Page99 show={someCondition} />
     </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The Appbar is sticky so it always shows on the top.
Each page component has a button which is always on the top of that page:

```
const styles = theme => ({
      button: {
              width:'100%',
      },
    });

class Page99 extends Component {

  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
         <div>
            <Button variant="contained" className= {classes.button}>
              Action Button
            </Button>
         </div>
        {/* Some other stuff */>
     </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

I know want this button to always be right under the appbar. So when the user scrolls down this button should remain sticky just like the appbar does. I tried to set the positioning to sticky hoping it would stack underneath it but it wouldn't. The appbar is dynamic so I don't know the exact height it will be since on different resolutions it will look different so I couldn't use something like fixed positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can set position of page container as relative and set button as absolute. 
the you can align it to top right of the page or wherever you want.

Check this fiddle is this is what you need

```css
.componentparent {
  position: relative;
  height:100px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
}

.otherelements{
  top: 70px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-container">
  <div> your app bar </div>
  <div class='componentparent'>
    <button class='button'>my button</button>
    <div class='otherelements'>your component</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What do I set the absolute to when I don't know the size of the appbar? I don't think absolute would make it stack underneath the appbar either.

Answer (score 0):

Place your button inside your appbar and set your button to position to absolute and add top: 100% to move it exactly at the bottom of appbar.